# How to get values from csv files and iterate through column

Tags: python, list, csv, reader

My csv File sample :

```
'Date','Category','Ability'
'21,2,5','Sparrow','Air,land'
'4,5,6','Eagle','Air,Land'
```

My current code:

```
with open(Filepath,'r') as f :
 user_read=csv.reader(f)
 dict_date=[line['Date'] for line in user_read]
print(dict_date)
```

Error :

> `TypeError : list indices must be integer or slices,not str`

My expected Output :

```
[21,2,5,4,5,6]
```

Any ideas.. So my Category and Ability has seperate Dictionary

Comment: `csv.reader` gives you a _list_, which you index using integers, e.g. `line[0]` gives the first element. If you want to reference your element using the column name, use `csv.DictReader`

Comment: Also note that your list comprehension is going to give you a list of lists. Since you seem to want a flattened output, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/843953

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing the rows as dicts, which is available through [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), and also you're not setting the [`quotechar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quotechar) for the dialect you're using which therefore defaults to `"`.

The following does both and works in the way you want.

```py
import csv
from io import StringIO

# I’m using StringIO to avoid writing a file,
# if the data is in a file keep using with open(…) as f
buf = StringIO(
    """\
'Date','Category','Ability'
'21,2,5','Sparrow','Air,land'
'4,5,6','Eagle','Air,Land'
"""
)

with buf as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, quotechar="'")
    date = [
        int(v) for row in reader for v in row["Date"].split(",")
        ]

print(date)  # [21, 2, 5, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: I am getting the same error.Why you used the 'buf'....We need to read the csv file that might be more that 100 Rows and columns

Comment: I used a StringIO to avoid writing a file, you should keep on opening your file the same way in with. PS, this code runs without error.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import csv


all_data = []
with open("data.csv", "r") as f_in:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in, quotechar="'")

    next(reader)  # skip header

    for row in reader:
        all_data.extend(map(int, row[0].split(",")))

print(all_data)
```

Prints:

```py
[21, 2, 5, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Yes it works,But why we have to give row[0]..There is no certainty we can tell the "Date " would be Cell[0,0]So is that possible to get values using header name...?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplice it using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.csv_reader("input.csv")
output = df['Date'].to_list()
```

The output will be:

```
['21,2,5', '4,5,6']
```

Comment: I dont want to use pandas....My Policy wont allow that to install additional libraries..your o/p has 2 elements,but i need 6 elements ....we need to remove" ' ' " using regex or anyother function...Any idea on removing single quotes

Answer (score 0):

I didnt use pandas due to policy restriction
Below the code which worked for me

```
Date_values=[]
with open(users_read,'r') as f:
  reader=DictReader(f)
  for row in reader:
    Date_values+=row['Date'].split(",")
  print(Date_values)
```